# Is it possible to move a ui element from one location to the other using fading?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uikit, fade

I would like to be able to fade out a UIView from location A and fade it in at location B *at the same time*.  Is this possible with iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create an image of the view, put it on screen (in an image view) over the actual view, set the view's alpha to 0, set its frame (or adjust layout constraints) to put it in a new position, then start an animation which fades out the image, and fades in the actual view.

Something like this should work:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *fadingView;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topCon;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *iv;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)moveView:(id)sender {
    UIImage *viewimage = [self imageWithView:self.fadingView];
    self.iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.fadingView.frame];
    self.iv.image = viewimage;
    [self.view addSubview:self.iv];
    self.fadingView.alpha = 0;
    self.topCon.constant = 200; // topCon is IBOutlet to the top constraint to the superview

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.fadingView.alpha = 1;
        self.iv.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.iv removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height), view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes something along these lines:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

    self.viewA.frame = CGRectMake... // middle point
    self.viewA.alpha = 0.0f;

    }completion:^ (BOOL finished) 
 {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

    self.viewA.frame = CGRectMake... // final point
    self.viewA.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
 }];
```

Comment: But that ends up just fading it out.  I would need another animation to fade it in.

Comment: you can chain animations, so you have the fade out until X location and the fade it in until the final destionation.

Comment: That's a nice effect, but not what I'm looking for.  Essentially I would like the view to be in "two places at the same time" as they fade.